# Combining models trained on different data sets

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I'm building a model to predict the near-future movement of a signal in a time series. I have 5 separate data sets to work off of, but they cannot be combined into one large set for methodological reasons.

Since I'm assuming that the behavioral patterns of the signal I'm trying to predict is highly similar between all of the sets, I'd like to train on 4 of the sets and use the last for testing.

What methods can I use to build 4 models one-to-one on 4 distinct training sets, and combine the resulting models to produce a master model?